# Bootstrap 5 alert not closing (using Vue)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I am working on a Vue project and I have no idea why this alert is not closing. the commented out section is what I initially wanted to work, but I substituted it for the code on the bootstrap website and it still does not close.

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <!--<div style="height: 80px">
        <div v-if='isError' class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible show animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
                {{loginError}}
            </div>
    </div>
    -->
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
        <strong strong>Success!</strong> This alert will fade away when clicking the × button.
    </div>
<div class="modal-dialog modal-login animate__animated animate__fadeInDown">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="avatar text-center">
                    <i class="fas fa-user mt-2 fa-3x"></i>
                </div>              
                <h4 class="modal-title">Member Login</h4>   
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="" @submit.prevent>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 ipt" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" v-model="email">      
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control mb-3 ipt" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" v-model="password"> 
                    </div>        
                    <div class="form-group row px-3">
                        <button type="submit" @click="login" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-btn">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <router-link to='/Signup'>New user? Click here to sign up!</router-link>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Side note, for some reason, the site is chopping off my template end tag. it is there, though.

Comment: Can you include all the relevant Vue code? The [markup works as expected](https://www.codeply.com/p/GMRmO7KX1C) without Vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you are using VUE, but since you didn’t show the whole code, I suppose the error is Doesn't work because you haven't enabled Bootstrap, more specifically JavaScript

Мне

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```